# How to have "input" (or is it context?) dependent hotstrings/hotkeys ?

Tags: autohotkey

I want a hotkey or hotstring (whatever is easier), so I can easily convert e.g.

1:5  into  [1,2,3,4,5] or
3:7 into [3,4,5,6,7]  etc..

I want this to work for all integers...
So I want "multiple variants of the same hotstring" (or, if easier: a hotkey that works somewhat similar: e.g. pressing strg + h and typing 1:3 should produces [1,2,3]  )

It should recognize that I typed a number followed by colon followed by another number, and then expand correspondingly..

I looked into the Input function, but it does not seem to be exactly what I want..

I don't need a working solution. Hints & links or keywords for further googling are already helpful..

Comment: in Autohotkey you can not use the character : this character will be used in many functions for example in hotstring :*:btw::bytheway - and in hotstring you can use only one string variable that can replace into a other string variable - the only thing what you can do is to use a (loop function) + use a (write/read windows registry functions) lo100hi500go - :*::go = read lo variable + read hi variable + start loop + send result + reset lo and hi value - :*:1:: check registy if is lo or hi + then read registry variable lo or hi+calculate it with +1 +write lo registry with that new value

Comment: l1h5g into [1,2,3,4,5] or l3h7g into [3,4,5,6,7] etc... the AhK codes can be something like this - :*:l:: RegWrite, REG_SZ, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, software\variables,loworhigh,lo return -  :*:h:: RegWrite, REG_SZ, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, software\variables,loworhigh,hi return - :*:g:: ...return - :*:0:: ...return - :*:1:: ...return - :*:2:: ...return - :*:3:: ...return - :*:4:: ...return - :*:6:: ...return - :*:7:: ...return - :*:8:: ...return - :*:9:: ...return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After typing +h or pressing strg+h, type two numbers to produce the desired outcome:

```
:*:+h::
^h::    
    nr := ""  ; empty variable's content
    end_nr := ""
    Input, var, L2 ; Length limit=2
    ; Input, var, L2  V ; V: Visible
    If var is not integer
    {
        MsgBox, "%var%" is not integer
            return
    }
    first_nr := SubStr(var, 1, 1)  
    second_nr := SubStr(var, 0)
    if (first_nr >= second_nr)
    {
        MsgBox, "%first_nr%" is greater or equal "%second_nr%"
            return
    }
    Loop
    {
        nr++    ; increase the number in the variable "nr" by 1 in each iteration
        if (nr < first_nr)
            continue    
        If (nr = second_nr)
            break   
        end_nr .= nr . "," ; concatenate the outputs by adding a comma to each one
    }
    If (first_nr = 0)
        MsgBox, "0,%end_nr%%second_nr%"
    else
    MsgBox, "%end_nr%%second_nr%"
return
```